# How to change Mac Mini from a mirrored RAID set to one drive?

Tags: crash, mac-mini

Just recently the Mac Mini I use for development/as a server had crashed. The most information I could get from it was that one of the drives in the mirrored RAID pair had crashed. Is there any way that I can solve this problem by removing a drive from one side of the pair?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a mirrored RAID, you should be able to still power it on with only one functional hard disk. To fix this problem, replace the crashed hard drive with a new one and rebuild the RAID mirror in the Disk Utility application.